# Differential equation: $e^{xy^2}\frac{x}{x^2+1}\,dx - e^{y^2x}\,dy = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have no idea how to solve this and would love some help.

> $$e^{xy^2}\frac{x}{x^2+1}\,dx - e^{y^2x}\,dy = 0$$

Comment: Did you mean for the two exponential factors to coincide?  If so, then you can just divide through by that factor to obtain a straight forward equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is equivalent to

$$\frac{x}{x^2+1}dx-dy=0$$
which is exact.